# Why are these objects returned by copy and not by move?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, move-semantics

Why are the value instances returned by getA() and getA2() returned using the copy constructor and not the move constructor?

I'm using visual studio community 2017, but godbolt gcc/20 and onlinegdb give the same results.

```
struct A { 
    int *buff;
    A() {
        cout << "A::constructor\n";
        buff = new int[1000000];
    } 
    A(const A& a) {
        cout << "A::copy constructor\n";
        buff = new int[1000000];
        memcpy(buff, a.buff, 1000000*sizeof(int));
    }
    A(A&& original)
    {
        cout << "Move constructor" << endl;
        buff = original.buff;
        original.buff = nullptr;
    } 
    ~A() { cout << "A::destructor\n"; delete[] buff; }
};

A getA()
{
    A temp[1];
    temp[0].buff[0] = 7;
    return temp[0]; 
}

A getA2()
{
    A temp;
    A& temp2 = temp;
    temp2.buff[0] = 7;
    return temp2; // copy on return value
}
int main() {
    A copy = getA();  // calls copy instead of move
    A copy2 = getA2();  // also calls copy instead of move
}
```

Comment: Are you compiling on C++17 or later? I suggest you to add the tag for the proper C++ standard version.

Comment: @prapin Using VS community 2017, no change detected in compiling with language set to 2014/2017/latest

Comment: Unrelated: `int main()` should be used instead of `void main()`

Comment: Try compiling it with optimizations enabled (with `/O2`)

Comment: Neither can be copy elided (RVO or NRVO) since the don't fit into those constraints.  The first one isn't moving the result `return std::move(temp[0]);`; the second one also isn't moving the result `return std::move(temp2);`.  So a copy is done.

Comment: @Eljay I guess the OP means the "implicit move" rather than NRVO (which doesn't involve move).

Answer (score 0):

If the aim is to do **move construction** for the statements `A copy = getA();` and `A copy2 = getA2();` then it can be done by compiling with the flag `-fno-elide-constructors` with C++11 or C++14.

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YKCbVfkzDI9AvbLV).

Although from [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.5/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html)

> The C++ standard allows an implementation to omit creating a temporary which is only used to initialize another object of the same type. Specifying this option disables that optimization, and **forces G++ to call the copy constructor in all cases**.

So i am not sure why in your case, this options enables move construction. This maybe a bug or lack of understanding of the concept about what is going on here from my side. And so i will delete this answer if/when required(once i know why is this happening).

I couldn't fit this into a comment so posting here as an answer.